# ssh from Linux to Windows - why need so many slashes in path?

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, openssh

I am trying to run commands over `ssh` from Linux machine to Windows machine.

Windows machine have OpenSSHx64 installed

Following command with double quotes fails:

```
ssh user@win8-pc "ls -l \\\\172.21.15.120\\vol0slash"

ls: cannot access 172.21.15.120vol0slash: No such file or directory
```

The same command with single quotes still fails, but at least display single slash:

```
ssh user@win8-pc 'ls -l \\\\172.21.15.120\\vol0slash'
ls: cannot access \172.21.15.120vol0slash: No such file or directory
```

Surrounding path with single quotes almost works, but still one root slash is missing:

```
ssh user@win8-pc "ls -l '\\\\172.21.15.120\\vol0slash'"
ls: cannot access \172.21.15.120\vol0slash: No such file or directory
```

Now finally adding fifth slash to UNC path root, did the trick:

```
ssh user@win8-pc "ls -l '\\\\\172.21.15.120\\vol0slash'"
total 536
drwxr-xr-x 1 Admin Domain Users   0 Jan 23 08:33 GeneralSystemDiagnostic
drwxr-xr-x 1 Admin Domain Users   0 Jan 22 08:10 cifs
-rw-r--r-- 1 Admin Domain Users 336 Jan 23 12:00 linux.txt
drwxr-xr-x 1 Admin Domain Users   0 Jan 19 14:11 nfs
```

Can anyone explain the logic behind this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslash is special symbol in `bash` and quite much in all Linux shells, therefore if you need to use it, it has to be escaped using another `\` (backslash). The command is [passed through the remote `bash`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332466/how-does-ssh-run-a-command/332467#332467) such as

```
bash -c "ls -l '\\\\\172.21.15.120\\vol0slash'"
```

which transfers evaluates the special characters and makes it look like

```
ls -l '\\\172.21.15.120\vol0slash'
```

when it is supposed to run.

The problem with using odd number of backslashes will end up evaluating as a special character, so you should go with even number, if you want to see a backslash in the end.

The other thing is how the arguments are interpreted by `ls` on Windows (which I have no idea about). See the tests with simple `echo`:

```
$ ssh f25 "echo '\1'"
\1
$ ssh f25 "echo '\\1'"
\1
$ ssh f25 "echo '\\\1'"
\\1
$ ssh f25 "echo '\\\\1'"
\\1
```

Similarly you can explain the original command without `'`:

```
ssh user@win8-pc "ls -l \\\\172.21.15.120\\vol0slash"
```

gets already in local shell (because it is not in `'`)

```
ssh user@win8-pc "ls -l \\172.21.15.120\vol0slash"
```

and remote shell gets already

```
bash -c "ls -l \\172.21.15.120\vol0slash"
```

which evaluates to

```
bash -c "ls -l \172.21.15.120vol0slash"
```

and to

```
ls -l 172.21.15.120vol0slash
```

which is obviously not existing.